# YAML. Doctrine 1.x. one-to-many relation

Tags: yaml, yml, doctrine

ДОброго времени суток.

Появился следующий вопрос.

- Есть Doctrine ORM 1
- Есть Yaml
- Нет Symfony

Задача:

Составить one-to-many схему, а именно:

- Таблица Modules (id, name)
- Таблица ModulesData (id, module_id, name, value)

Задача: 
 Составить схему 1 модуль ко многим ModulesData филдам со связью Modules.id = ModulesData.module_id

Бился много, бился часто, но до конца не въехал как решается сия задача.
Примерно получилось следующее :

```
Modules:
  columns:
    name:
      type:     string(32)
      unique:   true
      notnull:  true
  relations:
    ModulesData:
      class: ModulesData
      local: module_id
      foreign: id
      type: many
      foreignType: one
      alias: ModulesData
      foreignAlias: Modules

ModulesData:
  columns:
    module_id:
      type:     integer(4)
      notnull:  true
    name:
      type:     varchar(32)
    value:
      type:     string()
  relations:
    Modules:
      class: Modules
      local: id
      foreign: module_id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      alias: Modules
      foreignAlias: ModulesData
```

Но, к сожалению, такая конструкция (как и множественные другие попытки) не дали должного результата :-(

Надеюсь, Вам не тяжело будет подсказать в чем косячек ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось:

```
Modules:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type:     string(32)
      unique:   true
      notnull:  true
  relations:
    ModulesData:
       class: ModulesData
       local: id
       foreign: module_id
       type: many
       foreignType: one
       alias: ModulesData
       foreignAlias: Modules
       onDelete: CASCADE

ModulesData:
  columns:
    module_id:
      type:     integer(4)
      notnull:  true
    name:
      type:     string(32)
    value:
      type:     string()
  relations:
    Modules:
      class: Modules
      local: module_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      alias: Modules
      foreignAlias: ModulesData
      onDelete: CASCADE
```